# Pragma in conditional macro

Tags: c++, macros, pragma

C++ Question
I would like to write a macro who looks like this :

```
#define ACTIVATION 2

#define MY_MACRO(Condition)
__pragma(warning(push))
#if( Condition > ACTIVATION )
__pragma(warning(error:1000))
#endif
```

In other words, I want to disable a warning with a condition.
But this is not working because my macro is only defined by the first line :

```
#define MY_MACRO(Condition)
```

And I can't write

```
#define MY_MACRO(Condition) \
#pragma(warning(error:4996) \
#if( Condition > ACTIVATION ) \
#pragma(warning(error:4996) \
#endif
```

or

```
#define MY_MACRO(Condition) \
__pragma(warning(push)) \
#if( Condition > ACTIVATION ) \
__pragma(warning(error:1000)) \
#endif
```

because "#" seems to be not interpreted after "\"

Thanks for any help.

Comment: From where do you get `Condition`?

Comment: I think it's better to not use `#define`, but instead `#include` a file with your `#if`s